# how to grep the values from mongodb

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, middleware

New to development. I am trying to grep the values from JSON file. Can some one help me on this.

```
[{
    "State": "New York",
    "City": "Queens",
    "Cars": {
        "gas": {
            "USAMade": {
                "Ford": ["Fordcars", "Fordtrucks", "Fordsuv"]
            },
            "OutsideUS": {
                "Toyota": ["Tcars", "Ttrucks", "TSUV"]
            }
        },
        "electric": {
            "USAMade": {
                "Tesla": ["model3", "modelS", "modelX"]
            },
            "OutsideUS": {
                "Nissan": ["Ncars", "Ntrucks", "NSUV"]
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "State": "Atlanta",
    "City": "Roswell",
    "Cars": {
        "gas": {
            "USAMade": {
                "Ford": ["Fordcars", "Fordtrucks", "Fordsuv"]
            },
            "OutsideUS": {
                "Toyota": ["Tcars", "Ttrucks", "TSUV"]
            }
        },
        "electric": {
            "USAMade": {
                "Tesla": ["model3", "modelS", "modelX"]
            },
            "OutsideUS": {
                "Nissan": ["Ncars", "Ntrucks", "NSUV"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

]

1. How to list the type of cars like ( gas/electric)?
2. once i get the type, i want to list the respective country of made ( USAMade/OutsideUS).
3. After that i want to list the models ( Ford/Toyota)?

Comment: Do you have JSON or value stored in mongodb?

Comment: this JSON is inside in MongoDB and you want MongoDB to do this processing, or you just have a JSON file and you want to do this with javascript

Comment: JSON in  MongoDB. I want call these values from browser. 
Example on Frontend.
When users select State, it's automatically list the  city details. 
When user select city, next option is select cars. 
When user select cars , it have to provide list of types ( gas/ electric)
when he select gas, it has to list USMade or outsideusa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets suppose you have the documents in the file test.json , here it is how to grep using linux shell tools cat,jq,sort,uniq:

```
  1) cat test.json  | jq '.[] | .Cars | keys[] ' | sort | uniq
 "electric"
 "gas"

  2) cat test.json  | jq '.[] | .Cars[] | keys[] ' | sort | uniq
  "OutsideUS"
  "USAMade"

  3) cat test.json  | jq '.[] | .Cars[][] | keys[] ' | sort | uniq
  "Ford"
  "Nissan"
  "Tesla"
  "Toyota"
```

If your data is in mongoDB , I suggest you keep this distinct values in single document in separate collection and populate the frontend page on load from this collection and  the document can look something like this:

```
{
State:["Atlanta","Oregon"],
City:["New York" , "Tokio" , "Moskow"],
Location:["OutsideUS" ,"USAMade"],
Model:["Ford","Toyota","Nissan"]
}
```

You don't need to extract distinct values from database every time your front page loads since it is not scalable solution and at some point it will become performance bottleneck ...

But if you want it anyway to get only the distinct keys from mongoDB based on selection you can do as follow:

1.

```
 mongos> db.test.aggregate([   {"$project":{"akv":{"$objectToArray":"$Cars"}}} ,{$unwind:"$akv"} ,{ $group:{_id:null , "allkeys":{$addToSet:"$akv.k"}   } }] ).pretty()

 { "_id" : null, "allkeys" : [ "gas", "electric" ] }
```

2. mongos> db.test.aggregate([   {"$project":{"akv":{"$objectToArray":"$Cars.gas"}}} ,{$unwind:"$akv"} ,{ $group:{_id:null , "allkeys":{$addToSet:"$akv.k"}   } }] ).pretty()
   { "_id" : null, "allkeys" : [ "USAMade", "OutsideUS" ] }
3. 

```
mongos> db.test.aggregate([   {"$project":{"akv":{"$objectToArray":"$Cars.gas.USAMade"}}} ,{$unwind:"$akv"} ,{ $group:{_id:null , "allkeys":{$addToSet:"$akv.k"}   } }] ).pretty()
{ "_id" : null, "allkeys" : [ "Ford" ] }
```

Comment: Both queries worked as expected. Thank you